# How can I hide media manager link (and other ones) from non logged in users in Dokuwiki?

Tags: php, dokuwiki

I want to hide media manager links from non logged in users in Dokuwiki. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589912/dokuwiki-how-can-i-hide-media-manager-link-from-non-logged-in-users/15590098#15590098?newreg=b047236eb7ed44b5ba8aa5bf2f00e064) tread, but I have some follow up questions:

- Is this still the way to go to achieve this (removing those links) in the last version of Dokuwiki ("detritus")?
- If yes, **where should the PHP code be placed into /lib/tpl/dokuwiki/tpl_header.php?** At the end of the file? Into a particular section? It doesn't matter?
- Will non-admin users that are logged in still have access to the links? I mean I just want to remove them for non-logged users, not to all non-admin users.